# Does Azure AD B2C expose a metadata endpoint as relying party?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

AD FS is configured with custom policies as a claims provider on Azure AD B2C using either WS-Federation and SAML 1.1 or SAML 2.0.

Do Azure AD B2C expose a metadata endpoint as relying party which can be used by the AD FS when configuring Azure AD B2C as relying party? 
I'm interested in both WS-Federation/SAML and SAML 2.0 metadata.

** Edited **

The following metadata url do not work: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<yourtenant>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_<yourpolicy>/Samlp/metadata`

When the metadata is called the following error is returned:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C does expose a metadata endpoint when using Custom Policies**.

It can be found at this URL:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<yourtenant>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_<yourpolicy>/Samlp/metadata
```

**EDIT:** **B2C as a SAML RP is *not* officially supported at this time, however it is possible to enable it via custom policies.** If you are interested in this feature, make sure to [vote for it](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334323-saml-protocol-support) in order to support it and get updates on its progress.

There is no good documentation on how to do this outside of these docs:

- [Outdated walkthrough](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Walkthroughs/RP-SAML.md), compliment it with the StackOverflow posts below.
- [Azure Active Directory - Custom Policy Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45553943/azure-active-directory-custom-policy-error/45561177#45561177)
- [Issue when calling New-CpimCertificate for Azure AD B2C custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612747/issue-when-calling-new-cpimcertificate-for-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy/45620347#45620347)

Comment: Please see the edited message the metadata url do not work. I have tried with both base and base extensions policy.

Comment: It does work provided that you configure it correctly. Unfortunately, at this time I can't offer much help as to how to troubleshoot your policy for this (this is why that feature isn't even in preview yet).

Comment: Here's an example of a working one: https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/sacacorpb2c.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_signinsamlsf/Samlp/metadata

Comment: Thanks for the answers regarding SAML 2.0. Are there also a metadata endpoint for WS-Federation?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment of writing SAML2 metadata endpoint works with this idptp=TechnicalProfile-id variabel:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/<yourtenant>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1a_<yourpolicy>/Samlp/metadata?idptp=<TechnicalProfile-id>
```

This TechnicalProfile must have the following definitions:

```
<Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
<CryptographicKeys>
 <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ADFSSamlCert"/>
 <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ADFSSamlCert"/>
</CryptographicKeys>
```

P.S. Microsoft should really document these features.